# Perl XML get element node using XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I would like to replace the element node of my XML file, but I did not even succeed to get the node. My code below works for other child nodes but not the `id` node.

Here is my XML file:

```
<header>
    <idset id="100">                            
        <a>item_a</a>
        <b>item_b</b>
    </idset>
</header>
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use XML::LibXML;

my $file = 'test.xml';
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->load_xml(location => $file);

my($object11) = $doc->findnodes('/header/idset');
say 'a: ',$object11->findvalue('./a');
say 'b: ',$object11->findvalue('./b');
say 'id: ',$object11->findvalue('./id');
```

Current Result:

```
a: item_a
b: item_b
id:
```

Expecting Result:

```
a: item_a
b: item_b
id: 100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `id` is an attribute, not an element. You need to use a different selector style in your xpath expression.

```
say 'id: ',$object11->findvalue('./@id');
```

In xpath, an attribute is targeted with `@foo`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev for a short summary of this and other xpath syntax.

Comment: The reason the syntax is different for attributes and elements is that an element could have an attribute and an element with the same name.